# Does anybody know the name of the discrete distribution with these properties?

Tags: statistics

I'm looking for a distribution which has the following properties.  I don't know what it's called so I'm having a hard time finding references to it.

Properties:

- Domain is over a finite range of integers (distribution is discrete and truncated)
- Range is over the reals
- The sum over the distribution is equal to 1
- The first and second moments (mean and variance) are defined and are independent of one another
- The entropy of the distribution is maximized given the above constraints.

A normal distribution would fit these criteria if the domain was over all of the reals.  Likewise, a truncated normal distribution would fit if the domain were in a range of reals.

The binomial distribution can't be right because there's only one free parameter p which affects both the mean and variance.  Likewise the hyper-geometric distribution doesn't fit either.

Does anybody know if this distribution has a name?

Comment: Mean and variance are numbers, not events or random variables, so it does not make sense to say they are "independent of each other."

Comment: Hi @Michael - I mean in the sense that one can be changed without affecting the other.  Maybe orthogonal?  I fully admit the terminology I'm using could be wrong.  Feel free to correct if you think there's a better wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is again a discrete, truncated Gaussian. With Lagrange multipliers, the objective function is

$$
\sum_n p_n\log p_n+\lambda\sum_np_n+\mu\sum_nnp_n+\nu\sum_nn^2p_n\;.
$$

Setting the derivative with respect to $p_i$ to zero yields

$$
\log p_i+1+\lambda+\mu i+\nu i^2=0\;,
$$

which yields a Gaussian, with the three Lagrange multipliers determined by the three (transcendental) conditions given by the normalization, mean and variance.

Comment: Thanks @joriki.  That makes sense.  My final question would be if you knew if there was a closed form expression for a discrete truncated Gaussian.  I've found [link](http://www.wseas.org/multimedia/journals/mathematics/2017/a545806-984.pdf) which looks promising - working through changing from a centered mean to an arbitrary mean right now.